# Не работает pygame.transform.rotate()

Tags: python, pygame

```
player_1 = pygame.image.load('sprites/Blue.png')
...
def draw():
    sc.fill(white)
    sc.blit(player_1, (p1.x, p1.y))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.transform.rotate(player_1, 135)
```

Ничего не меняется. Персонажа нарисовало, а дальше как стоял, так и стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Результат нужно присваивать куда-то, я так понимаю, ну и отрисовывать:

```
def draw():
    sc.fill(white)
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(player_1, 135)
    sc.blit(rotated_image, (p1.x, p1.y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Спасибо, безумно помогли